# ThreeJs - 3D model edges not parallel in Orthographic camera view

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on an application where I am importing a 3D model. I have used an orthographic camera as I need a fixed depth. But I notice that at one angle the edges of the model are slightly skewed inwards. Attached the image below for your reference. Not really sure what's happening. Can someone help me out here? [image]

Here is the code:

```
import { OrbitControls } from "/OrbitControls.js";
import { GLTFLoader } from "./GLTFLoader.js";


//three js
let camera, controls, scene, renderer, loader, sprite, spriteBehindObject, spriteBehindObject2,spriteBehindObject3,  sprite2, sprite3;
const annotation01 = document.querySelector(".annotation01");
const annotation02 = document.querySelector(".annotation02");
const annotation03 = document.querySelector(".annotation03");
const annotation04 = document.querySelector(".annotation04");
const annotation05 = document.querySelector(".annotation05");
const annotation06 = document.querySelector(".annotation06");
const annotation07 = document.querySelector(".annotation07");
const annotation08 = document.querySelector(".annotation08");
const annotation09 = document.querySelector(".annotation09");
const annotation10 = document.querySelector(".annotation10");
const annotation11 = document.querySelector(".annotation11");

const annotationInfo = document.querySelector(".annotationInfo");
var gltfObj = new THREE.Object3D;

const frustumSize = 300;

const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const clickMouse = new THREE.Vector2();
const hoverMouse = new THREE.Vector2();


let SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
let SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
let aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;

let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas-window');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
// canvas.width = 600;
// canvas.height = 400;
let canvasAspect = canvas.width / canvas.height;

//execute
init();

function init() {
  // Scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xc2c2c2);

  // Camera
  // camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, canvas.width / canvas.width, 2, 1500); 
  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(frustumSize * aspect / - 2, frustumSize * aspect / 2, frustumSize / 2, frustumSize / - 2, -10000, 10000);
  camera.position.set(-150, 125,-150);


  // const cameraPole = new THREE.Object3D();
  scene.add(camera);
  // cameraPole.add(camera);

  // Lights
  var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0x4f4f4f,0x000000,4.5);
  scene.add(light);
  
  const lights = [];
  lights[0] = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.8, 0.1);
  lights[1] = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.8, 0.1);
  lights[2] = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.8, 0.1);

  lights[0].position.set(0, 2000, 0);
  lights[1].position.set(1000, 2000, 1000);
  lights[2].position.set(-1000, -2000, -1000);

  lights[0].castShadow = true;
  lights[1].castShadow = true;
  lights[2].castShadow = true;

  scene.add(lights[0]);
  scene.add(lights[1]);  
  scene.add(lights[2]);


  // var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x4f4f4f, 0x000000, 1);
  // // scene.add(light);

  //Axes
  const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
  // scene.add(axesHelper);
  // axesHelper.position.x = 200;
  axesHelper.position.y = 15;

  //plane
  const planes = new THREE.Object3D();
  scene.add(planes);

  const width = 30;  // ui: width
  const height = 240;  // ui: height

  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height);

  function makeInstance(geometry, zPosition, name) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x1E9FC0, opacity: 0.1, transparent: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
    let plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    planes.add(plane);

    plane.position.x = 60;
    plane.position.y = 0.01;
    plane.position.z = zPosition;

    plane.rotation.z = (Math.PI)/2;
    plane.rotation.x = (Math.PI)/2;
    plane.name = 'STM-' + name;
    return plane;
  }

  const planesArr = [
    makeInstance(geometry, -190, '01'),
    makeInstance(geometry, 15, '02'),
    makeInstance(geometry, 60, '03'),
    makeInstance(geometry, -235, '04'),
    makeInstance(geometry, 105, '05'),
    makeInstance(geometry, -150, '06'),
    makeInstance(geometry, -105, '07'),
    makeInstance(geometry, -25, '08'),
    makeInstance(geometry, 165, '09'),
    makeInstance(geometry, 210, '10'),
    makeInstance(geometry, 255, '11')
  ];


  //gltf 
  loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load("./VC/PlantModel.gltf", function (gltf) {
    gltfObj = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(gltfObj);
    gltfObj.position.z = 75;
    gltfObj.position.x = -580;
    gltfObj.scale.x = 10;
    gltfObj.scale.y = 10;
    gltfObj.scale.z = 10;
  
  });

  //renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, canvas });

  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(canvas.width, canvas.height);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  // controls.minZoom = 1;
  // controls.maxZoom = 55;
  // controls.minPolarAngle = 1;
  // controls.maxPolarAngle = 1;

  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);

  function onWindowResize() {
    //ortho
    const canvasAspect = canvas.width / canvas.height;

    camera.left = - frustumSize * canvasAspect / 2;
    camera.right = frustumSize * canvasAspect / 2;
    camera.top = frustumSize / 2;
    camera.bottom = - frustumSize / 2;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }



  function render() { 
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    updateScreenPosition();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    planesArr.forEach(() => {});
    // controls.update();
    render();

  }

  function updateScreenPosition() {
    const vector01 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, -190);
    const vector02 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, 15);
    const vector03 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, 60);
    const vector04 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, -235);
    const vector05 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, 105);
    const vector06 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, -150);
    const vector07 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, -105);
    const vector08 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, -25);
    const vector09 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, 165);
    const vector10 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, 205);
    const vector11 = new THREE.Vector3(-55, 1, 255);

    const canvas = renderer.domElement;

    vector01.project(camera);
    vector02.project(camera);
    vector03.project(camera);
    vector04.project(camera);
    vector05.project(camera);
    vector06.project(camera);
    vector07.project(camera);
    vector08.project(camera);
    vector09.project(camera);
    vector10.project(camera);
    vector11.project(camera);

    vector01.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector01.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector01.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector01.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    vector02.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector02.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector02.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector02.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    vector03.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector03.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector03.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector03.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    vector04.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector04.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector04.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector04.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    vector05.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector05.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector05.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector05.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    vector06.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector06.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector06.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector06.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    vector07.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector07.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector07.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector07.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    vector08.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector08.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector08.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector08.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    vector09.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector09.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector09.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector09.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    vector10.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector10.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector10.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector10.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    vector11.x = Math.round((0.5 + vector11.x / 2) * (canvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio));
    vector11.y = Math.round((0.5 - vector11.y / 2) * (canvas.height / window.devicePixelRatio));

    annotation01.style.top = `${vector01.y}px`;
    annotation01.style.left = `${vector01.x}px`;

    annotation02.style.top = `${vector02.y}px`;
    annotation02.style.left = `${vector02.x}px`;

    annotation03.style.top = `${vector03.y}px`;
    annotation03.style.left = `${vector03.x}px`;

    annotation04.style.top = `${vector04.y}px`;
    annotation04.style.left = `${vector04.x}px`;

    annotation05.style.top = `${vector05.y}px`;
    annotation05.style.left = `${vector05.x}px`;

    annotation06.style.top = `${vector06.y}px`;
    annotation06.style.left = `${vector06.x}px`;

    annotation07.style.top = `${vector07.y}px`;
    annotation07.style.left = `${vector07.x}px`;

    annotation08.style.top = `${vector08.y}px`;
    annotation08.style.left = `${vector08.x}px`;
    
    annotation09.style.top = `${vector09.y}px`;
    annotation09.style.left = `${vector09.x}px`;

    annotation10.style.top = `${vector10.y}px`;
    annotation10.style.left = `${vector10.x}px`;

    annotation11.style.top = `${vector11.y}px`;
    annotation11.style.left = `${vector11.x}px`;
  }

animate(); 

  // window.addEventListener('click', event => {
  //   clickMouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  //   clickMouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  //   raycaster.setFromCamera(clickMouse, camera);

  //   const found = raycaster.intersectObject(planes, true);
  //   // const found = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

  //   console.log(found);
  //   if (found.length > 0) {


  //     document.getElementById("annInfo").innerHTML = found[0].object.name;
  //     document.getElementById("annInfo").style.visibility = 'visible';
  //     document.getElementById("annInfo").style.padding = '0 5px 0 5px';
  //     document.getElementById("annInfo").style.top = (event.clientY - 50) + "px";

  //     document.getElementById("annInfo").style.left = event.clientX + "px";
  //   }
  // });

  window.addEventListener('click', event => {
    //click
    clickMouse.x = (event.clientX / canvas.width) * 2 - 1;
    clickMouse.y = - (event.clientY / canvas.height) * 2 + 1;

    // hoverMouse.x = (event.clientX / canvas.width) * 2 - 1;
    // hoverMouse.y = - (event.clientY / canvas.height) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(clickMouse, camera);
    // raycaster.setFromCamera(hoverMouse, camera);

    const found = raycaster.intersectObject(planes, true);

    if (found.length > 0) {
      found[0].object.material.opacity = 0.4;
      for (let index = 0; index < planes.children.length; index++) {
        if (planes.children[index].name !== found[0].object.name) {
          planes.children[index].material.opacity = 0.1;
        }
      }
      console.log(found[0].object.uuid);
      annotationInfo.innerHTML = 'KPIs for ' + found[0].object.name;
      document.getElementById("annInfo").style.padding = '0 5px 0 5px';
      document.getElementById("annInfo").style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById("annInfo").style.top = (event.clientY - 50) + "px";
      document.getElementById("annInfo").style.left = (event.clientX + 10) + "px";

      // var styleElem = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
      // styleElem.innerHTML = "#ann:before {background: green;}";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("annInfo").style.visibility = 'hidden';
      for (let index = 0; index < planes.children.length; index++) {
        planes.children[index].material.opacity = 0.1;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: A bit hard to understand what the issue is from your arrows. Could you describe also the expected behaviour?

Comment: The model edges kind of look like \   /. I want them to be parallel like |  |

Comment: You're using OrbitControls, which might be adding some rotations to your camera. Or maybe it's an issue with the geometry itself in your GLTF.

Comment: I think I got it. Although my camera is pointed at the origin, the model is not at the origin. I guess this explains why the edges have a slight distortion. Anyways I changed the camera to Perspective